# Plotting bars with 5 min interval and adding a line

Tags: python, plot, plotly, bar-chart

I am trying to plot closing price with positive and negative sentiment. I was able to plot it as the picture below; however, the colors are not showing properly for the bar chart. Any ideas how to change them?

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig2 = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
fig2.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data.index,y=data['close'],name='Price'),secondary_y=False)
fig2.add_trace(go.Bar(x=data.index,y=data['pos'],name='Positive'),secondary_y=True)
fig2.add_trace(go.Bar(x=data.index,y=data['neg'],name='Negative'),secondary_y=True)

fig2.show()
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: Looks right to me. What are you expecting, more opacity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- have implied you dataframe structure from your code and used **plotly** finance sample data set as starting point
- two things to look at wrt to layout

  1. make **Close** trace the primary trace at front
  2. review **bargroup** parameter and reduce **bargap** to zero

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv"
)

# make plotly dataset compatible with OP implied structure
data = df.set_index(pd.date_range("1-Jan-2022", freq="5Min", periods=len(df))).rename(
    columns={"AAPL.Close": "close", "dn": "neg", "up": "pos"}
)

fig2 = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
fig2.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=data.index, y=data["close"], name="Price"), secondary_y=False
)
fig2.add_trace(go.Bar(x=data.index, y=data["pos"], name="Positive"), secondary_y=True)
fig2.add_trace(go.Bar(x=data.index, y=data["neg"], name="Negative"), secondary_y=True)


# a few changes to make layout work better
#  1. put close at front
#  2. reduce "whitespace" in bars
fig2.update_layout(
    yaxis={"overlaying": "y2"}, yaxis2={"overlaying": None}, barmode="overlay", bargap=0
)
```

[image]